# Adding object to the beginning of generic List<T>

Tags: c#, .net

Add method Adds an object to the end of the `List<T>`

What would be a quick and efficient way of adding object to the beginning of a list?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Well, `list.Insert(0, obj)` - but that has to move everything. If you need to be able to insert at the start efficiently, consider a `Stack<T>` or a `LinkedList<T>`

Comment: Or just pretend the beginning is the end (invert all your indexes so i = list.Length - i and iterate from back to front)

Comment: True - that would be good to remove the Stack<T> case - but if you need more versatility, LinkedList<T> may have a part to play.

Comment: Another approach would be to create a placeholder entry in your `List<T> someList` (`someList.Add(null)`) and when you're ready, put your real value in: `someList[0] = real`

Answer (score 9):

```
List<T> l = new List<T>();
l.Insert(0, item);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can insert items at the beginning of the list, but that is not very efficient, especially if there are many items in the list.

To avoid that you can redefine what you use as beginning and end of the list, so that the last element is the beginning of the list. Then you just use Add to put an element at the beginning of the list, which is much more efficient than inserting items at position zero.